# How can I modify these?

Tags: disassembly, assembly, debugging, c++, x86-64

So I'm onto something interesting, I asked the less direct way but failed to meet the requirements in terms of explanation

So here it is, how would I go about editing these the same way I would go about editing them in the code?
[image: how]

In reality I would set these to '0' ,how would I go about this with the Debugger?

Comment: Your "set these to '0'" is highly ambiguous. These functions return the *string address* for some internal variables -- presumably you want to set their *value* to 0, right? Not the string contents? Then you need to trace back where these functions are called from and get their value assigned.

Comment: Do you want to set rax to 0? Press space and type "xor rax, rax". Anyway I think it won't be good for software you are editing.

Comment: do you mean this? https://i.imgur.com/zdWPgvz.png , doesn't make much sense as there is no "DS" , also in the aforementioned less direct post someone said : (**4831c9** xor rcx, rcx ),,,,,, AND YES, I do mean change the Variable recoil to 0.

Comment: There is little chance that nulling the rax here will change variable recoil to 0, you want to null register which is supposed to hold string, not that one with recoil.

Comment: And how do I find it according to what I got? ty btw

Comment: Please make the title more descriptive

Answer (score 1):

the instruction lea loads the Effective Address of its operand

so after executing **lea rcx, qword ptr ds:[xxxxxxx]**

rcx will hold the address **xxxxxxx**

so if you are sure you need rcx to be 0 in that instruction simply wipe the address from that specific operand

that is make **48:8d05 xyzabcd  as 48:8d0425 00000000**

or assemble **lea rax,qword ptr ds:[0]**

keep in mind this requires one extra byte because of rip relative addressing
8d05 00000000 will address the next instruction in x64
and will destroy the ret opcode

having said that what you are trying to do simply doesnt make sense
that instruction returns an address which will be acted upon
returning 0 to process further will surely result in access violation
down the line

assume the returned address holds a string whose length is checked further down
what will happen if NULL address was passed to that function

these kind of construction often represent a switch case or jump table construct
read about them

below is a samll poc that will generate code similar to your screenshot

```
#include <stdio.h>
char *a[] =  
{
    "Your Name","Our Name","Her Name","His Name","Their Name","That Name",
    "This Name","What Name","Why Name","Where Name","How Name","Whose Name",NULL
};
char *getname( int indx ) 
{
    switch(indx)
    {
        case 'a': return a[0];
        case 'b': return a[1];
        case 'c': return a[2];
        case 'd': return a[3];
        case 'e': return a[4];
        case 'f': return a[5];
        case 'g': return a[6];
        case 'h': return a[7];
        case 'i': return a[8];
        case 'j': return a[9];
        case 'k': return a[10];
        case 'l': return a[11];        
        default:  return "NoName";
    }
}
int main(int argc,char *argv[]) 
{
    if(argc !=2) return 0;
    printf("%s\n" , getname(*argv[1]));
    return 0;
}
```

[image]